# How to remove dialog margins?

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I'm trying to create a custom dialog to show a list of values at the bottom of screen.

How can I remove the dialog margins?

I want this...
[image]

I have this...
[image]

Dialog code:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_options);
    Window window = d.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
    d.show();
```

Solved! Better solution:

```
<style name="BottomOptionsDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orange_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/gray_light</item>
</style>
```

And use new Dialog(context, R.theme.BottomOptionsDialogTheme);

Comment: It's not better to use `Snackbar` in your situation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change your line:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
```

to:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

and add in your `styles.xml` with `parent` corresponding to your theme version.

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

---

But in your situation it can be better to use `Snackbar` in my opinion. [Here](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/) is tutorial.

Comment: It doesn't works. About Snackbar, how can I use a custom Snackbar? How can I define a custom layout to Snackbar? I need a list of options...

Comment: @FelipePorgeXavier please don't accept answer if it didn't work, thanks